# JS function clear my form variables values

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I wrote simple form with one text and one checkbox. Next i wrote function that run onsubmit form. When I submit form with onsubmit function text and checkbox values clear (text send only name of variable but without value, checkbox send nothing), else, without onsubmit function everything is fine. Why? There's a code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>

function addInput(task) {
document.getElementById('adminForm').innerHTML += "<input type='hidden' value="+task+" name=task/>";
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<form method="get" id="adminForm" onsubmit="addInput('Save')">
<input type="text" name="example"/>
<input type="checkbox" name="box" value="1"/>
<input type="submit" name="tas" value="Send"/>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several issues

1. You need to return false to stop the submission - you are just seeing your page being reloaded - alternatively show the result from the server to see it wa submitted
2. you need to update a div, not the form:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>

function addInput(task) {
  document.getElementById('adminForm').innerHTML += "<input type='hidden' value="+task+" name=task/>";
  window.console && console.log(task+" added");
  return false; // remove this if you want the form to be submitted
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<form method="get" onsubmit="addInput('Save')">
  <div id="adminForm"> 
    <input type="text" name="example"/>
    <input type="checkbox" name="box" value="1"/>
    <input type="submit" name="tas" value="Send"/>
  </div>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thx a lot, updating div instead of form worked. I spent 6 hours trying to resolve this problem;/